# SQL Consuming Values over Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a stored procedure which takes a table of holdings and assigns them to a table of buckets if they are a part of the same account. If a holding has the same account as a bucket, then I fill up the bucket with the amount of every holding under that account until a) the bucket is filled, in which case move on to the next bucket b) there are no more holdings left for that account, in which case move on to the next account

There are three scenarios for holdings and buckets of the same account:

1. The holdings fill up the buckets evenly - that is the sum of all the holdings = the sum of all the buckets
2. The holdings do not fill up all the buckets - in which case move on to the next account and ignore the remaining buckets for the previous account
3. The holdings overfill the buckets - in this scenario we ignore the remaining holdings

Each holding must be tagged with which bucket it's being assigned to and how much is being applied to each bucket. An example with some comments below:

```
Buckets
----------------------------------------
Bucket     BucketAccount     TotalAmount
1          GB111             30
2          GB111             50
3          GB222             100
4          GB333             150


Holdings                    (before execution)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID       Account       Amount      Bucket      AmountApplied       
1        GB111          50         null            null 
2        GB111          40         null            null
3        GB222          30         null            null
4        GB222          40         null            null    
5        GB333           5         null            null
6        GB333         145         null            null
7        GB333          50         null            null
```

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#buckets') Is Not Null)
Begin    
    Drop Table #buckets
End

CREATE TABLE #buckets         
(
    Bucket int,
    BucketAccount nvarchar(10),
    TotalAmount Decimal
);

insert into #buckets values 
    (1, 'GB111', 30),
    (2, 'GB111', 50),
    (3, 'GB222', 100),
    (4, 'GB333', 150)



If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#holdings') Is Not Null)
Begin    
    Drop Table #holdings
End

CREATE TABLE #holdings      
(
    ID int,
    Account nvarchar(10),
    Amount decimal,
    Bucket int null,
    TotalAmount decimal null    
);

insert into #holdings (ID, Account, Amount, Bucket, TotalAmount) 
values
    (1, 'GB111', 50, null, null),
    (2, 'GB111', 40, null, null),
    (3, 'GB222', 30, null, null),
    (4, 'GB222', 40, null, null),
    (5, 'GB333', 5, null, null),
    (6, 'GB333', 145, null, null),
    (7, 'GB333', 50, null, null)


select *
from
    (select 
        hold.Account,   maxIds.ID as SubTotalId, sum(hold.Amount) as PartAmount
    from #holdings hold
        inner join #holdings maxIds
            on hold.Account = maxIds.Account
            and hold.Id <= maxIds.ID            
    group by hold.Account, maxIds.Id) partHoldings

    right join 
        (select buckets.BucketAccount, subBuckets.Bucket, sum(buckets.TotalAmount) as PartAmount
        from #buckets buckets
            inner join #buckets subBuckets 
                on buckets.BucketAccount = subBuckets.BucketAccount
                and buckets.Bucket <= subBuckets.Bucket
        group by buckets.BucketAccount, subBuckets.Bucket) partBuckets

        on partHoldings.Account = partBuckets.BucketAccount
        and partHoldings.PartAmount >= partBuckets.PartAmount


select 
    -- * ,
    BucketAccount, Bucket, ID as holdingId,
    case 
        when MinHoldingCoveringBucket < Id and Id < MaxHoldingCoveringBucket then Amount
        when MinHoldingCoveringBucket = Id and Id = MaxHoldingCoveringBucket then PartAmount - prevTotalPartAmount
        when MinHoldingCoveringBucket = Id and Id <> MaxHoldingCoveringBucket then holdPartAmount - prevTotalPartAmount
        when MinHoldingCoveringBucket <> Id and Id = MaxHoldingCoveringBucket then PartAmount - holdPrevPartAmount
        else null 
    end as AmountApplied
from
    (select 
        holdingsBuckets.BucketAccount, holdingsBuckets.Bucket, holdingsBuckets.PartAmount, holdingsBuckets.prevTotalPartAmount  
        , IsNull(MinHoldingCoveringBucket, minAccountHoldingId) as MinHoldingCoveringBucket
        , IsNull(MaxHoldingCoveringBucket, maxAccountHoldingId) as MaxHoldingCoveringBucket

        , hold.ID, hold.Amount
        , partHoldings.PartAmount as holdPartAmount
        , partHoldings.prevPartAmount as holdPrevPartAmount
    from
        (select     
            topLimits.*
            , min(botLimits.SubTotalId) as MinHoldingCoveringBucket
        from
            (select 
                partBuckets.*   
                , min(partHoldings.SubTotalId) as MaxHoldingCoveringBucket  
            from
                (select subBuckets.BucketAccount, subBuckets.Bucket, sum(buckets.TotalAmount) as PartAmount, sum(buckets.TotalAmount) - subBuckets.TotalAmount as prevTotalPartAmount
                from #buckets buckets
                    inner join #buckets subBuckets 
                        on buckets.BucketAccount = subBuckets.BucketAccount
                        and buckets.Bucket <= subBuckets.Bucket
                group by subBuckets.BucketAccount, subBuckets.Bucket, subBuckets.TotalAmount) partBuckets

                left join 
                    (select 
                        hold.Account,   maxIds.ID as SubTotalId, sum(hold.Amount) as PartAmount
                    from #holdings hold
                        inner join #holdings maxIds
                            on hold.Account = maxIds.Account
                            and hold.Id <= maxIds.ID            
                    group by hold.Account, maxIds.Id) partHoldings

                on partHoldings.Account = partBuckets.BucketAccount
                and partHoldings.PartAmount >= partBuckets.PartAmount


                left join 
                    (select 
                        hold.Account,   maxIds.ID as SubTotalId, sum(hold.Amount) as PartAmount
                    from #holdings hold
                        inner join #holdings maxIds
                            on hold.Account = maxIds.Account
                            and hold.Id <= maxIds.ID            
                    group by hold.Account, maxIds.Id) partHoldings2

                on partBuckets.BucketAccount = partHoldings2.Account
                and partHoldings.SubTotalId >= partHoldings2.SubTotalId
                and partHoldings2.PartAmount > partBuckets.prevTotalPartAmount  

            group by partBuckets.BucketAccount, partBuckets.Bucket, partBuckets.PartAmount, partBuckets.prevTotalPartAmount) topLimits

            left join 
                (select 
                    hold.Account,   maxIds.ID as SubTotalId, sum(hold.Amount) as PartAmount
                from #holdings hold
                    inner join #holdings maxIds
                        on hold.Account = maxIds.Account
                        and hold.Id <= maxIds.ID            
                group by hold.Account, maxIds.Id) botLimits

                on topLimits.BucketAccount = botLimits.Account
                and botLimits.PartAmount > topLimits.prevTotalPartAmount
                and botLimits.SubTotalId < topLimits.MaxHoldingCoveringBucket

        group by topLimits.BucketAccount, topLimits.Bucket, topLimits.PartAmount, topLimits.prevTotalPartAmount, topLimits.MaxHoldingCoveringBucket) holdingsBuckets

        inner join 
            (select Account, min(Id) as minAccountHoldingId, max(id) as maxAccountHoldingId
            from #holdings
            group by Account) edgeAccountHoldings

            on holdingsBuckets.BucketAccount = edgeAccountHoldings.Account

        right join #holdings hold
            on holdingsBuckets.BucketAccount = hold.Account
            and IsNull(MinHoldingCoveringBucket, minAccountHoldingId) <= hold.ID
            and hold.ID <= IsNull(MaxHoldingCoveringBucket, maxAccountHoldingId)

        left join 
            (
            select 
                hold.Account,   maxIds.ID as SubTotalId, sum(hold.Amount) as PartAmount, sum(hold.Amount) - maxIds.Amount as prevPartAmount
            from #holdings hold
                inner join #holdings maxIds
                    on hold.Account = maxIds.Account
                    and hold.Id <= maxIds.ID            
            group by hold.Account, maxIds.Id, maxIds.Amount
            ) partHoldings

            on partHoldings.Account = holdingsBuckets.BucketAccount
            and hold.ID = partHoldings.SubTotalId) selectionData
```

After execution:

HoldingId 5 should be showing 40 in the amountApplied field instead of 70. We have applied 30 from the first holding, and then 40 applied from the second to sum to 70.

```
Holdings                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID       Account       Amount      Bucket      AmountApplied      Comments    
1        GB111          50           1              30          Applied 30. Bucket 1 is filled with 20 leftover, move to next bucket of same account
2        GB111          20           2              20          Insert new record. Applied 20 (from leftover in Bucket 1), and there is 30 leftover to cover in Bucket 2
3        GB111          40           2              30          Applied 30, 10 leftover in Bucket 2. We are out of holdings for this account, move on to next account
4        GB222          30           3              30          Applied 30, 70 leftover in Bucket 3
5        GB222          40           3            **70**        Applied 40, 30 leftover in bucket 3. Bucket is not filled and we are out of holdings for this account. Move on to next account 
6        GB333           5           4               5          Applied 5, 145 leftover in Bucket 4      
7        GB333         145           4             145          Applied 145, Bucket 4 is filled with 0 leftover, move on to next account
8        GB333          50          null          null          Skip as Bucket 4 is already filled
```

The scenario in which a bucket is underfilled is causing my script to work improperly. I'm hoping someone will be able to point out where I'm going wrong - I feel as though it's overengineered here. Also, I believe that doing this in a select rather than a series of updates may be causing this. Any assistance is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't think I understand how you intend for the negative holding amounts to work (admittedly, I didn't pore over your logic very closely.) I did make a stab and hopefully it's a useful start: https://rextester.com/BISE34431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the DDL I used:

```
create table Buckets (Bucket int, BucketAccount varchar(5), TotalAmount int);
insert into Buckets (Bucket, BucketAccount, TotalAmount) values
    (1, 'GB111', 30), (2, 'GB111', 50), (3, 'GB222', 100), (4, 'GB333', 150),
    (5, 'GB444', 20), (6, 'GB444', 20), (7, 'GB444', 20);

create table Holdings (ID int, Account varchar(5), Amount int);
insert into Holdings (ID, Account, Amount) values
    (1, 'GB111', 50), (2, 'GB111', 40), (3, 'GB222', 30),
    (4, 'GB222', 40), (5, 'GB333', 100), (6, 'GB333', 250), (7, 'GB333', 50),
    (8, 'GB444', 15), (9, 'GB444', 30), (10, 'GB444', 10);
```

`GB444` has a situation where a single holding will span three different buckets which is a situation not represented by the sample data you provided. Note that I also edited the query to properly handle that case.

```
with b as (
    select *,
        sum(TotalAmount) over (partition by BucketAccount order by Bucket) -
          TotalAmount as e,
        sum(TotalAmount) over (partition by BucketAccount order by Bucket) as f,
        sum(TotalAmount) over (partition by BucketAccount) as AccountSize
    from Buckets
), h as (
    select *,
        sum(Amount) over (partition by Account order by ID) - Amount as a,
        sum(Amount) over (partition by Account order by ID) as b
    from Holdings
)
select
    h.Account, b.AccountSize,
    h.ID, h.Amount, b.Bucket, b.TotalAmount as BucketSize,
    case
        when h.a >= b.e and h.b <= b.f then h.Amount
        when h.a <  b.e and h.b <= b.f then h.b - b.e
        else b.f - case when h.a > b.e then h.a else b.e end
    end as AmountApplied,
    case
        when h.a >= b.e and h.b <= b.f then 'Type 1: ' +
               cast(b.f - h.b as char(3)) + ' unfilled'
        when h.a <  b.e and h.b <= b.f then 'Type 2: ' +
               cast(b.f - h.b as char(3)) + ' unfilled'
        else case when h.a > b.e then 'Type 3: ' else 'Type 4: ' end +
               cast(h.b - b.f as char(3)) + ' overflows'
    end as Scenario,
    case when h.a >= b.e and h.b <= b.f then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Spans,
    case when h.b >= b.f then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Depletes
from h inner join b on b.BucketAccount = h.Account and h.a < b.f and h.b > b.e
order by h.Account, h.ID, b.Bucket;
```

This precomputes the positions of holdings and buckets in cumulative fashion as though stacked along the number line. The join is then based on asking whether each holding range overlaps each bucket range.

The output includes additional potentially useful columns that describe how each segment of the holding was applied to the bucket.

**Also**

For fun I [played around](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99f181d80fb0f32922c9be308270fe00) with a way of visualizing this a little bit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Shawn. I'm noticing a similar issue to yours as Tom's. Basically the amountApplied being tracked is incorrect if a holding is filling up a partially filled bucket. You can see the example here in Row 2 and Row 8: https://rextester.com/CFXJY47453

Comment: Oddly, the subsequent computations look good - it's just the scenario if a bucket is filled with a leftover holding then the AmountApplied displays the TotalAmount of the bucket rather than the remainder applied that's left in the holding

Comment: @ssm495 I think a tweak in the `else case ...` line fixes that problem.

Comment: Shawn, just taking a further look at this. Can you explain in a little more detail what a, b, e, and f are?

Comment: Put all the holdings/buckets in a series and those values are the start and end ranges of each one. E and F were intended to represent "empty" and "full". The other two are just A and B for lack of a better name.

Comment: Got it. If I wanted to track a holding that's used across multiple buckets being depleted (i.e. reach zero) how could I accomplish this? Basically the Amount of the Holding - AmountApplied of the next row. I tried min(RemainingHolding) OVER (Partition BY ID) - SUM(AmountApplied) OVER (Partition BY Id ORDER BY BucketAccount) Total where RemainingHolding is just Amount - AmountApplied

Comment: @ssm495 I added a new case to handle and corrected my logic for the condition that a holding spans three or more buckets. There are a couple of new columns that should help you get the extra flag you're looking for.

Comment: Funny enough I edited your original logic to account for the 3 buckets with ELSE CASE WHEN b.f - h.a > b.TotalAmount THEN b.TotalAmount. The extra columns are helpful but I'm more looking for something that explicitly shows the holding depleting to zero. It should show at what value the holding starts, then after subtracting each amount applied shows the remaining balance. If it's consumed the ending amount is 0. Obviously for holdings that are consumed in one go just show 0. This scenario is only evident when a single holding spans 3 or more buckets.

Comment: I think you might be looking for one of these: `case when h.b <= b.f then 'Consumed' else '' end as Consumed,
        max(case when h.b <= b.f then 'Consumed' else '' end) over (partition by h.ID) as Consumed2` Balance of the holding at each allocation?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to have the 'runningTotal' or balance be tracked at each allocation. I'm able to see if something is 'consumed' if it switches HoldingIds. But to actually track the amount that is left. How would I go about this? So for the first holding that spans multiple buckets, you take the Amount of that holding, and then subtract the AmountApplied of the next row and store that. Then you use that number and subtract the AmountApplied of the next row.

Comment: So basically you want `sum(<AmountApplied>) over (partition by ID order by Bucket) as CumulativeAmountApplied`?

Answer (score 1):

This was interesting, and I'm not 100% sure what to do with a negative holding - assume it increases the available space in the bucket??

Anyway, this will do it for you if the above is true:

```
;with row1 as
(
    select ID, Account, Amount, b.Bucket, b.TotalAmount, 
        row_number() over (partition by Account order by ID, b.Bucket) rn
    from #holdings h
    join #buckets b on b.BucketAccount=h.Account
) 
, allocations as
(
    select ID, Account, Amount, Bucket, TotalAmount, 
        convert(decimal,case when Amount<=TotalAmount then Amount else TotalAmount end) as Allocated,
        convert(decimal,case when Amount>=TotalAmount then Amount-TotalAmount else 0.0 end) as HoldingRemaining,
        convert(decimal,case when Amount>=TotalAmount then 0.0 else TotalAmount-Amount end) as BucketRemaining
    from row1 where rn=1
    union all
    select ID, Account, Amount, Bucket, TotalAmount,
        convert(decimal,case when HoldingRemaining<=BucketRemaining then HoldingRemaining else BucketRemaining end) as Allocated,
        convert(decimal,case when HoldingRemaining>=BucketRemaining then HoldingRemaining-BucketRemaining else 0.0 end) as HoldingRemaining,
        convert(decimal,case when HoldingRemaining>=BucketRemaining then 0.0 else BucketRemaining-HoldingRemaining end) as BucketRemaining
    from (
        select h.ID, h.Account, h.Amount, b.Bucket, b.TotalAmount, 
            case when h.ID=a.ID then HoldingRemaining else h.Amount end as HoldingRemaining,
            case when h.Bucket=a.Bucket then BucketRemaining else b.TotalAmount end as BucketRemaining
        from allocations a
        -- Move to next holding if required
        join #holdings h on h.Account=a.Account
            and (
                (HoldingRemaining>0 and h.ID=a.ID)
                or (HoldingRemaining=0 and h.ID=a.ID+1)
            )
        -- Move to next bucket if required
        join #buckets b on b.BucketAccount=a.Account
            and (
                (BucketRemaining>0 and b.Bucket=a.Bucket)
                or (BucketRemaining=0 and b.Bucket=a.Bucket+1)
            )
     ) q
)
select * from allocations order by Account, ID, Bucket
```

Result:

```
ID  Account Amount  Bucket  TotalAmount Allocated   HoldingRemaining    BucketRemaining
1   GB111   50      1       30          30          20                  0
1   GB111   50      2       50          20          0                   30
2   GB111   40      2       50          40          0                   10
3   GB222   30      3       100         30          0                   70
4   GB222   40      3       100         40          0                   60
5   GB333   -100    4       150         -100        0                   250
6   GB333   250     4       150         150         100                 0
```

Comment: Tom, thanks for your response. After further review, there won't be a situation with a negative holding - I've updated my tables to reflect this.

Comment: Tom, unfortunately not. Noticing a few issues.There is an issue in the scenario when a bucket is underfilled by a holding, and then subsequently filled by the next holding. The 'AmountApplied' column for the holding that fills it displays the total amount of the bucket rather than the true amount applied. Example seen here in Row 2 and Row 8: https://rextester.com/JFK22534

Comment: Also noticing an issue where the holding remaining is not being properly tracked. In row 2, we should have allocated 150 to Bucket 1. That means that Holding 2 has 150 remaining (300 from the original holding minus 150 that was allocated to Bucket 1). Therefore we can only allocate 150 to Bucket 2 (row 3)